# Modified Forms of Law of Iterated Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Could you please clarify how we can evaluate the below modified forms of the law of iterated expectation?

The well know law of iterated expectation states,

$$\operatorname{E} (X) = \operatorname{E} ( \operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y))$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation

How can this be applied to evaluate the below two modifications?

## 1)

$$\operatorname{E} ( g(X)\operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y)) = ?? $$

## 2)

$$\operatorname{E} ( h(Y)\operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y)) = ?? $$

Please let me know if you need any further information or if this is not clear.

Comment: "Please let me know if you need any further information" Indeed! And to begin with, how you define the conditional expectation E(X|Y) for two given random variables X and Y.

Comment: @Did Please note, the standard definition of conditional expectation is what I am referring to, as also used on the Wikipedia link I have included. If there are other definitions that apply, please do mention.

Comment: ?? There is no definition of conditional expectation on the WP page you linked to. I understand you have no definition in mind?

Comment: @Did no specific definition in mind; but whatever was used to derive the law of conditional expectation or tower rule in the Wikipedia page should apply here as well; Please do clarify if there are multiple definitions and how that would change the results... Totally understand that how you are seeing this could be very advanced and it would be helpful to know alternate approaches.

Comment: Here is a tip: when faced with a mathematical question that you cannot solve, *go back to the definitions*. That you could try to solve some conditional expectation problem with, if I understand your comments correctly, basically no definition of conditional expectation at hand, is rather stunning.

Comment: @Did thanks for this good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. 1) will read 
$$
\operatorname{E} ( g(X)\operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y)) = \operatorname{E} ( \operatorname{E}(g(X)\mid Y)\operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y));
$$
2) becomes
$$
\operatorname{E} ( h(Y)\operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y)) = \operatorname{E} ( h(Y)X).
$$

Both equations can be shown using the fact that 
$$
\operatorname{E} ( f(Y)Z) = \operatorname{E} ( f(Y)\operatorname{E} ( Z \mid Y))
$$
(this holds for $f(Y) = \mathbf{1}_A(Y)$ by definition and then extends by linearity and some limit procedure to "arbitrary" measurable $f$). Namely, for 1) take $Z = g(X)$, $f(Y) = \operatorname{E} ( X \mid Y)$; for 2), $Z=X$, $f(Y) = h(Y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide steps to the proofs or any source?

Comment: @user249613, done. Consult any advanced probability textbook (e.g. Durrett) for additional details.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I have accepted the answer; but might ask some questions if I still have doubts since this is an advanced topic for me. Much appreciated for this and pointing out a good source.